# PHP Force download not working

Tags: php, header, download, content-type, content-disposition

Here is my problem. I am trying to download a file using header. Here is my code:

```
$content_type = mime_content_type('uploads/MyBBIntegrator_v1.3.1.zip');
$file = 'uploads/MyBBIntegrator_v1.3.1.zip';
header("Cache-Control: public");
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyBBIntegrator_v1.3.1.zip');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile('uploads/MyBBIntegrator_v1.3.1.zip');
```

However, the only result of this is that the page displays the contents of the file (it is a text file) or a string of strange symbols if the file is image/zip/exe etc

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the Content-Length header and try..

Comment: Its working for me? which browser?

Comment: As a start, remove all unneeded or undefined response header fields (Content-Description, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Cache-Control: public...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `mime_content_type()` is deprecated, you should try another method to fetch the MIME value.

I have checked your code and it works fine on my server, and it works fine for me. You should check for INI directives which might block the download. Try a fresh install server.

Also, there should be no output generated by the script before the snippet you put into your question.